# Connecting Garmin GPS Device to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gps, garmin

I Have a problem regarding connecting my Garmin GPS 18x USB
to ArcMap. It is not working.Can you tell me any advice.

Comment: What documentation are you following?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: A quick read about Garmin GPS 18x USB reveals that it outputs data only in Garmin format. Not sure if ArcMap can read that.

Answer (score 1):

I have used DNR GPS (http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html) to connect Garmin handheld receivers to ArcMap. I have not used a GPS 18x USB but DNR GPS supports the Garmin protocol so should work in the same way as handheld devices. Make sure you have the correct GPS drivers installed.

MX GPS (http://www.mxgps.com/) may be another option but from the information on the website it doesn't seem to be able to stream data.